# Didn't find details about Attribute 'Type' (SCRATCH) of API instances.attachDisk()

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I want to use instances.attachDisk API. In it's description of request body fields, one of the field is 'type'. Below is the description of it:

type enum Specifies the type of the disk, either SCRATCH or PERSISTENT. If not specified, the default is PERSISTENT.

While adding disk I only see two types 'Standard persistent' and 'SDD persistent'.

So i would like to know below details of "SCRATCH" type:

1. What does "SCRATCH" means here?
2. How to add scratch disk?
3. Where is documentation of "SCRATCH" disks.

I have gone through storage related docs but didn't found any specific note regarding "SCRATCH" disks.

Please help me in it.

Answer (score 1):

From [1]: Create an instance with local SSDs when you need a fast scratch disk or cache and do not want to use instance memory. Also use local SSDs when your workload itself is replicated across multiple instances.

This means that in case you want to use scratch disks, you should specify and use Local SSD disks for your instance, and use this as the documentation reference you asked for.

As (also) described here [2], local SSD is often the preferred option for your scratch disks, caching layers and scale-out databases like NoSQL.

As you may see, for Compute Engine VM instances, scratch disks doesn't have a different meaning, they are just used by specifying Local SSD disks.

---

Links:

[1] https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/#localssds

[2] https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/announcing-price-cuts-on-local-ssds-for-on-demand-and-preemptible-instances